# Verifying application state using checksum at runtime

Tags: c#, checksum

A checksum is common way to make sure that a file's integrity isn't compromised. What I need is an integrity check not on a file but on the application state in a C# application. Think of a instance of a class that I want to instantiate and manipulate on physically seperate machines under the assumption that - as long as the checksum remains the same - the state of the instance is identical on all machines, too. The class instance may contain several fields or collections of other classes, some public but most private, so it's not trivial and the object hierarchy (amount of objects in the collections etc) will change at runtime.

Is there a better way than serializing the relevant object-hierarchy into a memory stream which then is passed to a standard checksum algorithm?

Comment: Clearly a checksum / hash is capable of collisions, so this isn't a guarantee but how is what you're doing different to checking value equality of these objects locally?  i.e. if you have to make a value-behaviour GetHashCode for your root object what would make that not able to be your checksum?  Or an extension of the concept to a larger space if 32bits is not enough to prevent false positives

Comment: To quote the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) "You should never persist or use a hash code outside the application domain in which it was created, because the same object may hash across application domains, processes, and platforms."  The reason for this is that the default GetHashCode implementation oftentimes uses the memory address of the object.

Comment: Yes I know, but that would be reference equality.  If your root level object is capable of value equality then everything in its object graph must be _capable_ of value equality, or irrelevant to (root's) value equality.  I'm not necessarily saying you should _use_ GetHashCode, I'm saying your question is actually how to implement value equality (and thus hashing) correctly for your object.  If you _have_ serialization already there is a 'natural' way to do this,  what kind of serialization do you already have?

Comment: In my current test project I scattered the [Serializable] attribute allover the code base. I was hoping for a clever, less invasive way of doing it. (Considering that this change might be impossible to do for any kind closed-source 3rd party dependancies)